# Else if Statement ( the last condition is always picked

Tags: javascript

```
if (q1 == "1-25") {
    score = 0;
}
else if (q1 == "26-40"){
    score = 5;
}
else if (q1 == "41-60"){
    score = 8;
}
else (q1 == "60+")
    score = 10;
```

this is a segment of my code from a multi-choice test but no matter what option I pick, the score variable always chooses 10

A possible error in the format of my code?

Comment: Where does the variable `q1` come from? can you paste that code as well?

Comment: this cannot be answered unless you will post the code where `q1` is set

Comment: You are missing an `if` in the last `else if`. Or you need to omit the condition.

Comment: Else shouldn't be followed by a condition. Javascript doesn't require curly braces so it's probably executing the condition as a statement (since else doesn't accept a condition) and then the final score is a separate statement outside of the if else logic.

Comment: @messerbill I beg to differ.

Comment: before you hit the `if` block, put `console.log(q1)` and see what it is.  The logic suggests that you are not hitting the conditionals at all.  Also you have `else (q1 =="60+")`... was that intended?  The conditional in the parathesis will not matter as else is triggered if the above conditions fail.

Comment: @john you beg to differ what?

Comment: @john yes, i got it. I did not see that condition after the `else`.

Comment: would it be make sense to turn else (q1 == "60+"){
  score = 10;  into   else if  (q1 == "60+"){
  score = 10;  instead?

Comment: depends on how your program works. If that list of conditions is exhaustive, turn it into an `else if`. If there may be other values for `q1`, just keep the `else` (without the condition)

Comment: update: removed the conditions from the last else statement, now able to get different scores, however, most combinations of answers aren't giving me the right scores

Comment: example is if  i pick the last answer from each question i get 45 which is right  but it seems most of the other combinations dont give the right score

Comment: I'm reverting your question to its original state. Please, don't edit your post this much, especially after it's been answered correctly. Open a new question instead.

Comment: Also, you should accept @john's answer (or any other answer, as they're all correct)

Comment: ok thanks alot guys ,still get used to stackoverflow atm !

Answer (score 2):

`else` shouldn't be followed by a condition. Javascript doesn't require curly braces so it's probably executing the condition as a statement (since `else` doesn't accept a condition) and then the final score is a separate statement outside of the `if-else` logic.

If I add braces to **your current code**, you can see where the problem lies:

```
if (q1 == "1-25") {
    score = 0;
}
else if (q1 == "26-40"){
    score = 5;
}
else if (q1 == "41-60"){
    score = 8;
}
else 
{
    (q1 == "60+");
}
score = 10;
```

So you can see that, because you're using `else` rather than `else if`, the "condition" is executed by the else, evaluated to true/false and then thrown away. And then, after the if statement is done, score is set to 10.

Comment: fixed that for you

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this:

```
 } else (q1 == "60+");
 score = 10;
```

Thanks to ASI, `(q1 == "60+")` is the expression that is run in the else part, `score = 10` is always executed after the if/else. Might do:

```
  } else {
   score = 10;
  }
```

Or

```
 } else if (q1 == "60+"){
   score = 10;
 }
```

And please always use semicolons to seperate statements and curly braces to annotate blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is problem

```
else (q1 == "60+")
    score = 10;
```

You are missing `if`

Or remove this condition.

> Else cannot have condition